How can I avoid negative penalization in choice questions?
I have a closed exam with numeric and choice questions (True/False type or with several options to choose but only one is true) in a unique file: T2vas.Rnw
Since I do not want penalization for incorrect answers, I use
ee <- exams_eval(partial = TRUE, negative = 0, rule = "none")

or only ee <- exams_eval(rule = "none"), and then
exams2moodle("T2vas.Rnw",encoding = "UTF-8",n = 1,
  cloze = list(cloze_schoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_V"),
  name = "TeoriaVAcambioeval", choice = list(eval = ee))

The result in moodle is always {1:MULTICHOICE_V:=Verdadero~%-50%Falso} even if a change the negative value. Previous versions work correctly using just rule = "none".

Welcome to SO! You have a better chance of receiving useful answers if your question is minimal and reproducible. Here, we need to see (some of) your T2vas.Rnw file as wells as details of the packages you are using, their current versions, and the previous versions that behaved in the way you wanted.

Thanks for the question. You can use lm2.Rmd (or Rnw) as an illustration for your problem. I didn't have the time, yet, to look into this in detail. But it seems to be a bug in our package. I'll try to follow up as soon as I get round to having a closer look.

Does the workaround below solve your problem? Then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Otherwise please follow up with further details.

In recent versions we have simplified the exams2moodle() interface, especially with respect to cloze exercises. As a side product some of the possible eval specifications currently (version 2.4-1) do not work correctly. We will try to fix these as soon as possible.
If you use the recommended interface, then rule = "none" is processed correctly. The other eval options are not needed because partial = TRUE is the only option in Moodle anyway and you don't need negative points. Furthermore, you can drop the encoding argument because since version 2.4-0 UTF-8 is the only supported encoding anyway.
For illustration I will use the exercise lm2 which is a cloze exercise, also containing an schoice interaction at the end.
In summary, this should work for you:
exams2moodle("lm2.Rnw", rule = "none",
  cloze = list(cloze_schoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_V"))

We will also make rule = "none" the default for single-choice interactions in cloze exercises.
